# PowerShell App-V 5.0 SP3 server install

Tags: powershell, failed-installation, appv

I'm trying to make this script work which automates App-V 5.0 installation using PowerShell. I'm installing it on Windows Server 2012 R2 With SQL 2012. Whenever it reaches Invoke-Expression $installappv, nothing happens. I can see the setup file start for a few seconds in task manager, but nothing gets installed. Please help.

```
.\AppVInstall\AppVServer\appv_server_setup.exe /layout
$appvconf = Get-Content .\AppVInstall\AppVServer\AppV_Conf.ini
$appvparameters = $appvconf -join " "
$installappv = ".\AppVInstall\AppVServer\appv_server_setup.exe" + " " + $appvparameters
Invoke-Expression $installappv
```

This is the contents of the file ".\AppVInstall\AppVServer\AppV_Conf.ini"

```
/QUIET 
/ACCEPTEULA 
/MANAGEMENT_SERVER
/MANAGEMENT_ADMINACCOUNT="XXXX.local\XXXXX" 
/MANAGEMENT_WEBSITE_NAME="Microsoft App-V Management Service" 
/MANAGEMENT_WEBSITE_PORT="80" 
/DB_PREDEPLOY_MANAGEMENT 
/MANAGEMENT_DB_SQLINSTANCE_USE_DEFAULT
/MANAGEMENT_DB_NAME="AppVManagement" 
/PUBLISHING_SERVER /PUBLISHING_MGT_SERVER="testappvsvr.XXXX.local:80"; 
/PUBLISHING_WEBSITE_NAME="Microsoft AppV Publishing Service" 
/PUBLISHING_WEBSITE_PORT="81"
```

Comment: It _seems_ ok what you have but you do not show us what the ini file looks like so possible the issue is coming from there. You said the exe is starting but stop soon after so the beginning is ok. Lets look at your arguments.

Comment: /QUIET
/ACCEPTEULA
/MANAGEMENT_SERVER
/MANAGEMENT_ADMINACCOUNT="XXXX.local\XXXXX"
/MANAGEMENT_WEBSITE_NAME="Microsoft App-V Management Service"
/MANAGEMENT_WEBSITE_PORT="80"
/DB_PREDEPLOY_MANAGEMENT
/MANAGEMENT_DB_SQLINSTANCE_USE_DEFAULT
/MANAGEMENT_DB_NAME="AppVManagement"
/PUBLISHING_SERVER
/PUBLISHING_MGT_SERVER="http://testappvsvr.XXXX.local:80"
/PUBLISHING_WEBSITE_NAME="Microsoft AppV Publishing Service"
/PUBLISHING_WEBSITE_PORT="81"

Comment: There are a bunch of quotes in there that _might_ be causing an issue. My attention is drawn to that semi-colon that seems out of place as well

Comment: THAT IT! its the semi colon. Invoke Expression think that there is a new command

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Expression` is treating your string like 2 commands because of the semi-colon.

Consider the following statements.

Example 1

```
PS C:\temp> Invoke-Expression "echo test;stuff test"
test
stuff : The term 'stuff' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, ....output truncated...
```

Example 2

```
PS C:\temp> Invoke-Expression "echo 'test;stuff test'"
test;stuff test
```

In the first example the semicolon is not escaped or encased in quotes. It is a line terminator in PowerShell so it is treating `'stuff test'` as its own command `stuff` with `test` as an argument. I don't have a cmdlet or exe called `stuff` so I get an error. I think that's what happening to you. A chunk of your parameters are not being sent to `appv_server_setup.exe` .

In the second example the semicolon is in single quote so the entire string is output on one line.

I don't know if it needs to be there but that semicolon has to be addressed somehow so that `Invoke-Expression` does not see it all by its lonesome.

Perhaps you can wrap all the arguments in one set of quotes.

```
$appvparameters = "'$($appvconf -join "' '")'"
```

Comment: I tried your example. Using a set of quotes didn't allow the parameters to pass to the setup.exe

Comment: @KajuanByrd sorry that was  a bad idea. . Does that semicolon need to be there? See my edit for that. each argument is in its own set of quotes now.

Comment: the semicolon is not suppose to be there. I tried the updated version with each argument in its own set of quotes, but it's still not installing.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt I figured out the problem. The setup doesn't except changes to the default port numbers from the INI. Those parameters must be changed after the install. Thanks for your help Matt.